# Axis of a cylinder

Tags: geometry, surfaces

Could you explain to me what the axis of a cylinder is?

Is it a line that passes through the center?

Comment: And is parallel to the curved surface

Comment: So is the definition, a line that passes through the center and is parallel to the curved surface? What exactly do you means by "curved surface" ? @SS_C4

Comment: The surface which is not the two circles is the curved surface

Comment: If you are considering a cylinder which has two circles at the ends, the line joining the centers of the circles is the axis of the cylinder.

Answer (score 2):

A picture worth 1000 words:) The Z axis is the axis of the cylinder

[image]

Comment: Does it have to be always one of the axes $x,y,z$ ?

Comment: Not necessarily. If the cylinder is rotated, then the axis also rotates the same way. (Parallel to the curved surface ☺)

Comment: No. In this picture it is the Z. Will another image help you?

Answer (score 0):

If any straight line segment AB rotates w.r.t. another  parallel straight line XX (parallel means not skewed) called an *axis* (a.k.a. axle ) distance $r$ from it, rotating by a full $ 360^0,$ the surface so swept out in 3-space is the surface of a cylinder. By the process of sweeping in this manner the axial line is a  locus of all circle centers. When a circular rod rolls on a plane its axis also moves. A shaft in an electric motor or lathe has an an axis the is stationary in position and direction.

The cylinder has height or length $AB$ and curved/round area $ = 2\pi r AB$.